# JSON stringify objects excluding methods

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firebug, stringify

I'm working on a Firefox extension and I'm trying to stringify a JSON object.

I'm using this [stringify function](https://www.thomasfrank.se/json_stringify_revisited.html) but I'm getting this error:

`Could not convert JavaScript argument "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS"`

I really just care about the first level or two or properties inside the object, and I don't care about the methods / functions. Is there a simpler way to stringify an object if I don't need all this?

Here's the bit of code I'm using:

```
    var s=JSONstring.make('abc');

    try{

        Firebug.Console.log(gContextMenu);

        s = JSON.stringify(gContextMenu);

        Firebug.Console.log(s);
    }catch(e){
        Firebug.Console.log('error');
        Firebug.Console.log(e);
    }
    var s=JSONstring.make('abc');
    Firebug.Console.log(s);
    Firebug.Console.log(gContextMenu);
```

Here is the error in the console window:

[image]

This is what I was able to copy out of the Firebug console window:

http://pastebin.com/KPXceRag

Here is a screenshot of the object:

[image http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/2603/pictureos.png](http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/2603/pictureos.png)

Comment: Please provide a sample string that you want to stringify.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the object reference itself somehow?

Comment: @ChaosPandion - probably, yes. But the function I used was supposed to deal with recursion. I only copy / pasted the function, though, so perhaps it needs tweaking. I'm guessing JSON.stringify does not deal with it, or that is not always available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom function on your object called `toJSON()` that returns only the elements of the object you want. Somewhat counter-intuitively, your `toJSON` function should *not* return a JSON string - it just returns an object representing what should be used as the input for `JSON.stringify`.

For example:

```
// an object with some attributes you want and some you don't
var o = {
    a:"value1", 
    b:"value2", 
    doCalc: function() { return this.a + " " +  this.b } 
};
// define a custom toJSON() method
o.toJSON = function() { 
    return {
        a:this.a, 
        calc: this.doCalc() 
    } 
};

JSON.stringify(o); // '{"a":"value","calc":"value1 value2"}'
```

In your case, you should be able to define this method for `gContextMenu` on the fly, before calling `JSON.stringify`. This does require you to explicitly define what you want and don't want, but I don't think there's a better way.

**Edit:** If you want to pull all non-method values, you could try something like this:

```
o.toJSON = function() { 
    var attrs = {};
    for (var attr in this) {
        if (typeof this[attr] != "function") {
            attrs[attr] = String(this[attr]); // force to string
        }
    }
    return attrs;
};
```

You will probably end up with a few attributes set to `"[object Object]"`, but if all you want is inspection, this probably isn't an issue. You could also try checking for `typeof this[attr] == "string" || typeof this[attr] == "number"` if you wanted to get only those types of attributes.

Comment: How can we add a loop to return all properties but not methods? Or, perhaps all properties that are strings? I dont know which items will be present and was trying to grab all of them.